# My Angular Search results are returning all the values from the firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

This is the my-data.service where I get data from the firebase database.It is returning all the values irrespective of the search query

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
    import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
    import { Data } from './data';
    import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    import 'firebase/storage';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';

    @Injectable()
    export class MyDataService{
    ROOT_URL = 'https://vilaichal-aarambam.firebaseio.com/';
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {  }

     getArticles(query, start, end): Observable<any[]>{
        return this.db.list('Articles/',ref => name ? 
        ref.orderByChild("title").startAt('start').endAt('end'): ref
        ).valueChanges();
     }
```

The search article component where I get the response through the function and pass it to the Articles variable

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs/subject';
   import { MyDataService } from'../my-data.service';
   import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-article-search',
     templateUrl: './article-search.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./article-search.component.css']
   })
   export class ArticleSearchComponent implements OnInit {

      articles;
      startAt = new Subject();
      endAt = new Subject();

     startobs = this.startAt.asObservable();
     endobs = this.endAt.asObservable();
     q:any;
     constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.dataService.getArticles(this.q,this.startAt, this.endAt)
       .subscribe((article) => this.articles = article)
    }
    search($event){
      this.q = $event.target.value;
      this.startAt.next(this.q);
      this.endAt.next(this.q+"\uf8ff");
      }
     }
```

And finally the html where I retrieve the response and display it.

```
<input type="text" class="search" (keydown)="search($event)">

<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
  <h4 routerLink="article/{{article.title}}">{{article.title}}</h4>
</div>

<div *ngIf="articles?.length < 1">
<hr>
  <p>Sorry No Results</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check the request it sents? Are there `correct` params?

Comment: No @BotanMan I'm quite new to Angular. How to check Can you please help me. I Struggling :(

Comment: @BotanMan I logged out query variable, It is precisely showing the string what I enter in the search box

Comment: getArticles(query, start, end): Observable<any[]>{
    return this.db.list('Articles/',ref => query ? ref.startAt('start').endAt('end'): ref
  ).valueChanges();

This code is not processing :( Is this code is correct?